# Create docker network for vpn

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, vpn

I am trying to create several different docker-compose apps that utilize the same express VPN connection. Ideally what I would like to do is create a docker network called `vpn`, create a container called `expressvpn` that connects to a VPN and allows any container on the `vpn` network to connect to the VPN. I know I can create a docker container with a container network stack by specifying `--net container:expressvpn`. The problem with this approach is that any port I would like accessible by my local network needs to be forwarded in the `expressvpn` container. I also can't seem to use this approach with docker-compose.

So my question is: is there any such way to create a VPN network? Would it be possible to do this with a network plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You get anywhere with this?

If not, you can try what i do, for me it works. I also have a cron job that restarts the docker compose every 2 days, because i have had issues with the vpn reconnecting no matter what i do. restarting docker compose works just fine now.

Use docker-compose.yaml for all your containers you want to use for vpn.

Put all the ports for all containers on the expressvpn container like this.

```
services:
  expressvpn:
     ports:
      - "8112:8112" #Deluge
      - "6881:6881/tcp" #Deluge
      - "6881:6881/udp" #Deluge
```

Then for each of the containers put the following. This will use the expressvpn container for internet access.

```
  deluge:
    depends_on:
      - expressvpn
    network_mode: "service:expressvpn"
```